# Do-while ignores condition

Tags: java

Numbers in "list" from 1 to 10, pick 2 of them by random (NOT equal) and show.

```
myRand = rand.nextInt(list.size());
myRand1 = myRand; 
do{
    myRand = rand.nextInt(list.size());
} while(myRand == myRand1);
// some print
```

Do-While should prohibit same values, but does not. Why?

Edit: More information.
List contains 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 (int).
myRand contains 2 for example.
Now myRand1 also contains 2. I do not want that. So I put the do-while for getting another value. It is again 2, still dont want that. So while does not end. Finally, value is 3. Now it can break the loop. But it seems to ignore the condition

Comment: Can you elaborate how you are discovering the code does not work?

Comment: `do-while` executes once even if condition is false very first time.

Comment: Rohit5k2 yes, thats the point. Otherwise it would be the same rand-number, which would be false

Comment: So what's the problem? It doesn't generate a second random number?

Comment: Yes, it does generate a second random number. But it sometimes is the same as the first. And I just don´t get why.

Comment: Okay so if it generates the same number again, does the loop trigger and it tries again?

Comment: *sometimes is the same as the first.* of course... there is a chance to get same numbre...

Comment: There's a 1/5 chance that every time you call `nextInt(list.size())` it's going to generate the same number. You have then said *"Finally value is 3. Now it can break the loop"* - surely this is what you want?

Comment: Scott: It does not. Thats exactly the problem

Comment: [your code works nice](http://ideone.com/x16DGY)

Comment: I do NOT want to have the same number twice.
I am completely aware that it CAN be the same number twice, but I dont what that to happen

Comment: Unless your RNG is http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25 the loop should work. Is it possible that you're doing something to the numbers after the loop?

Comment: Using the debugger shows that it works exactly like expected - if its the same number, it generates a new until it is different. Still sometimes getting the same numbers as output, I dont get it but thats another problem now. Thanks everybody

Comment: Actually, the code works as expected.`
   Random rand = new Random();
   for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000_000; i++) {
    Object myRand = rand.nextInt(5);
   Object myRand1 = myRand; 
   do{
       myRand = rand.nextInt(5);
   } while(myRand == myRand1);
   
   if (myRand == myRand1) {
    System.out.println("Same: " + myRand);
   }
  }`
It never prints "Same: <something>"

Comment: BTW, ensure that the list size is > 1. If it is 0, you are going to get IllegalArgumentException. If it is 1, the loop is not going to stop ever.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should not assign `myRand1 = myRand;`, [check this demo working](http://ideone.com/x16DGY)

```
Random rand = new Random(); 
int myRand = rand.nextInt(list.size());
int myRand1 = rand.nextInt(list.size());
while(myRand == myRand1){
    myRand = rand.nextInt(list.size());
}

System.out.println(myRand + " - " + myRand1);
```

**UPDATE:**
I created a new demo according your comment:

> I tried it, **still sometimes get the same number**. I just dont get why. This should be very simple but turns out to be mind-boggling as hell

This new demo is to make you sure **number is not repeating** and your problem (if still exists) is in another place of your code.

```
Random rand = new Random(); 
int myRand = rand.nextInt(2);
int myRand1 = rand.nextInt(2);
while(myRand == myRand1){
    myRand = rand.nextInt(2);
}

System.out.println(myRand + "-" + myRand1);
```

As you can see, I just changed the length of the list to make sure you only can have `0` and `1` numbers as output.

Output:

```
0-1

1-0

1-0

0-1

0-1

0-1
```

Comment: I tried it, still sometimes get the same number. I just dont get why. This should be very simple but turns out to be mind-boggling as hell

Comment: @Best_Where_Gives check my update, problem is not in the loop

Answer (score -1):

```
myRand1 = rand.nextInt(list.size());
myRand2 = myRand1;

while (myRand1 == myRand2) {
    myRand2 = rand.nextInt(list.size());
}
```

does this work?

Comment: It happens a lot down voting without comment. Ignore it.